How can I change the select to get all data in one block of rows?
I want to get employees information's  and Head of department name and custody officer
I did this query :
SELECT c.EMP_JOB_NO,
       f.ITEM_DESC_A ,
       e.DEPT_NAME_A as "emp_dept",
       a.DEPT_ID,
    b.DEPT_NAME_A as "clear_depts", 
    c.emp_name_a ,
    a.APPROVE_HOD  ,
    a.HOD_ID , null as "Head Name" , a.CUST_ID , null "cust name"
    FROM CLEARANCE_ORDERS_CUST a,
    CLEARANCE_DEPARTMENTS b , 
    clearance_emp_info c , 
    clearance_orders d , 
    clearance_departments e ,
    sys_codes f
WHERE a.DEPT_ID = b.DEPT_ID
    -- and c.emp_id = a.hod_id
     and a.orders_id = 81
     and d.ORDER_NO = a.ORDERS_ID
     and d.EMP_NO = c.EMP_ID 
     and e.DEPT_ID = c.DEPT_ID
     and f.ITEM_NO = c.NATIONALITY
     and f.TABLE_NO = 108
     and f.HOSPITAL_NO = 720022
     union 
SELECT null,
       null ,
       null as "emp_dept",
       null,
       null as "clear_depts", 
       null ,
       null  ,
      null , 
      c.emp_name_a as "Head Name" , 
     null , 
     null 
    FROM CLEARANCE_ORDERS_CUST a,
    CLEARANCE_DEPARTMENTS b , 
    clearance_emp_info c , 
    clearance_orders d , 
    clearance_departments e ,
    sys_codes f
WHERE a.DEPT_ID = b.DEPT_ID
     and c.emp_id = a.hod_id
     and a.orders_id = 81
     and d.ORDER_NO = a.ORDERS_ID
    -- and d.EMP_NO = c.EMP_ID 
     and e.DEPT_ID = c.DEPT_ID
     and f.ITEM_NO = c.NATIONALITY
     and f.TABLE_NO = 108
     and f.HOSPITAL_NO = 720022
     union 
SELECT null,
       null ,
       null as "emp_dept",
       null,
       null as "clear_depts", 
       null ,
       null  ,
      null , 
      null as "Head Name" , 
     null , 
     c.emp_name_a as "cust name"
    FROM CLEARANCE_ORDERS_CUST a,
    CLEARANCE_DEPARTMENTS b , 
    clearance_emp_info c , 
    clearance_orders d , 
    clearance_departments e ,
    sys_codes f
WHERE a.DEPT_ID = b.DEPT_ID
     and c.emp_id = a.CUST_ID
     and a.orders_id = 81
     and d.ORDER_NO = a.ORDERS_ID
    -- and d.EMP_NO = c.EMP_ID 
     and e.DEPT_ID = c.DEPT_ID
     and f.ITEM_NO = c.NATIONALITY
     and f.TABLE_NO = 108
     and f.HOSPITAL_NO = 720022  

now the output divided into 3 parts one part for each select how can I concatenate the 3 select in one select and get all data in same rows , the difference between 3 select was I need to get employee name and department manager name and custody officer name
this condition different in each select
and d.EMP_NO = c.EMP_ID 

and c.emp_id = a.hod_id

and c.emp_id = a.CUST_ID

can I do one select and collect three conditions ?

From Oracle 12, use a LATERAL join and CASE expressions:
SELECT CASE j.type WHEN 1 THEN c.EMP_JOB_NO  END AS EMP_JOB_NO,
       CASE j.type WHEN 1 THEN f.ITEM_DESC_A END AS ITEM_DESC_A,
       CASE j.type WHEN 1 THEN e.DEPT_NAME_A END AS "emp_dept",
       CASE j.type WHEN 1 THEN a.DEPT_ID     END AS DEPT_ID,
       CASE j.type WHEN 1 THEN b.DEPT_NAME_A END AS "clear_depts", 
       CASE j.type WHEN 1 THEN c.emp_name_a  END AS emp_name_a,
       CASE j.type WHEN 1 THEN a.APPROVE_HOD END AS APPROVE_HOD,
       CASE j.type WHEN 1 THEN a.HOD_ID      END AS HOD_ID,
       CASE j.type WHEN 2 THEN c.emp_name_a  END AS "Head Name",
       CASE j.type WHEN 1 THEN a.CUST_ID     END AS CUST_ID,
       CASE j.type WHEN 3 THEN c.emp_name_a  END AS "cust name"
FROM   CLEARANCE_ORDERS_CUST a
       INNER JOIN CLEARANCE_DEPARTMENTS b
       ON (a.DEPT_ID = b.DEPT_ID)
       INNER JOIN clearance_orders d
       ON (d.ORDER_NO = a.ORDERS_ID)
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT 1 AS type, d.EMP_NO AS id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, a.hod_id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, a.CUST_ID FROM DUAL
       ) j
       INNER JOIN clearance_emp_info c
       ON (c.emp_id = j.id)
       INNER JOIN clearance_departments e
       ON (e.DEPT_ID = c.DEPT_ID)
       INNER JOIN sys_codes f
       ON (f.ITEM_NO = c.NATIONALITY)
WHERE  a.orders_id = 81
AND    f.TABLE_NO = 108
AND    f.HOSPITAL_NO = 720022


Wouldn't there need to be aggregation to collapse the rows into a single row per employee?

@Boneist No, the OP uses UNION to get rows from 3 different queries and does not use any aggregation so they appear to want the 3 rows (with lots of NULL values in two of them) rather than one aggregated row. The OP may need to add DISTINCT (since they are using UNION rather than UNION ALL - but unless they have duplicates in their tables the UNIONed queries should not produce duplicates).

Assuming that EMP_ID is a primary (or, at least, unique) key of your clearance_emp_info table and, as you are selecting only one column each for the department head and custody officer information, you can do this in two other ways in addition to MT0's answer:
Correlated subqueries - this has the advantage that the result can be cached for each correlated condition, meaning that if you have several rows in your base query that have the same, e.g. hod_id, the subquery will only be ran once and the result stored and resused for subsequent rows that match:
SELECT c.emp_job_no,
     f.item_desc_a,
     e.dept_name_a AS "emp_dept",
     a.dept_id,
     b.dept_name_a AS "clear_depts",
     c.emp_name_a,
     a.approve_hod,
     a.hod_id,
     (SELECT emp_name_a FROM clearance_emp_info head WHERE a.hod_id = head.emp_no) AS "Head Name",
     a.cust_id,
     (SELECT emp_name_a FROM clearance_emp_info cust WHERE a.cust_id = cust.emp_no) AS "cust name"
FROM   clearance_orders_cust a
       INNER JOIN clearance_departments b ON a.dept_id = b.dept_id
     INNER JOIN clearance_orders d ON d.order_no = a.orders_id
     INNER JOIN clearance_emp_info c ON d.emp_no = c.emp_id
     INNER JOIN clearance_departments e ON e.dept_id = c.dept_id
     INNER JOIN sys_codes f ON f.item_no = c.nationality
WHERE  a.orders_id = 81
AND    f.table_no = 108
AND    f.hospital_no = 720022;

Additional outer joins - probably won't be as performant as the correlated subqueries, because the join conditions will be ran for each row in the base table:
SELECT c.emp_job_no,
       f.item_desc_a,
       e.dept_name_a AS "emp_dept",
       a.dept_id,
       b.dept_name_a AS "clear_depts",
       c.emp_name_a,
       a.approve_hod,
       a.hod_id,
       head.emp_name_a AS "Head Name",
       a.cust_id,
       cust.emp_name_a AS "cust name"
FROM   clearance_orders_cust a
       INNER JOIN clearance_departments b ON a.dept_id = b.dept_id
       INNER JOIN clearance_orders d ON d.order_no = a.orders_id
       INNER JOIN clearance_emp_info c ON d.emp_no = c.emp_id
       INNER JOIN clearance_departments e ON e.dept_id = c.dept_id
       INNER JOIN sys_codes f ON f.item_no = c.nationality
       LEFT OUTER JOIN clearance_emp_info head ON a.hod_id = head.emp_no
       LEFT OUTER JOIN clearance_emp_info cust ON a.cust_id = cust.emp_no
WHERE  a.orders_id = 81
AND    f.table_no = 108
AND    f.hospital_no = 720022;

N.B. note that I have converted your joins to use ANSI join syntax - this makes it easier to understand how the tables are joined, and the old-fashioned way of doing joins is ... well, out-dated!
MT0's answer may be more performant, since it's only querying clearance_emp_info once whereas both my queries select from the clearance_emp_info table three times, but I would definitely test all the queries against your data to see which one performed better if I were you.

In the OP's query they get 3 sets of rows based on different joins between a, c and d and in two of those three sets of rows the columns are mostly populated with NULL values. These queries do not replicate the data in the same format the the OP had it as you will not have the rows with mostly NULL values. The changing in formatting may be acceptable to the OP but would be very different than their current output.

It also does not filter the outer/correlated joined tables with the same join conditions as the c table is also filtered on d.emp_no = c.emp_id AND e.dept_id = c.dept_id AND f.item_no = c.nationality.

@MT0 I'm assuming that when the OP says how can I concatenate the 3 select in one select and get all data in same rows that they need the names of the head of department and custody in the same row as the other employee details, rather than on separate rows as they are at present. I.e. collapsing the three rows into one per employee. Of course, since the OP didn't provide sample data and expected output, it's just a guess!

Hence I said that the "formatting may be acceptable to the OP but would be very different than their current output". However, my second point still stands that you need to also add the same filters to the correlated sub-queries and outer joined queries that are on the c table otherwise those queries will not have the same filters on them as the OP is using.

As for the join conditions - I already stated up front that I was assuming that emp_id was unique, so the additional join conditions are unnecessary (and in fact, the original join conditions may be too restrictive - what if a manager is head of two departments?)

The outer joined query could look something like one of these options fiddle then you get all the same join conditions as the OP's query.
